# Spring boot data not inserted into the database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

The database is already created but when trying to insert new data in the database the data is not saved in the database and there are no errors that are show. I have tried to look for a solution from posted questions but none is solving the problem. I have not included the h2 dependency in the `pom.xml`. I have tried to implement `Serializable` in the user class but is not solving the problem either

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uwezo_banking

spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= 

spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query= SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.uwezotech</groupId>
    <artifactId>uwezotech</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>uwezotech</name>
    <description>An online banking web application</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**User.java**

```
package com.uwezotech.domain;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;


    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private String email;
    private String phone;


    @OneToOne
    private PrimaryAccount primaryAccount;    

    @OneToOne
    private SavingsAccount savingsAccount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Appointment> appointmentList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Recipient> recipientList;
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id"
    )}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, boolean enabled, String email, String phone, String confirmPassword, PrimaryAccount primaryAccount, SavingsAccount savingsAccount, List<Appointment> appointmentList, List<Recipient> recipientList, List<Role> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
        this.savingsAccount = savingsAccount;
        this.appointmentList = appointmentList;
        this.recipientList = recipientList;
        this.roles = roles;
    }


    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public PrimaryAccount getPrimaryAccount() {
        return primaryAccount;
    }

    public void setPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
        this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
    }

    public SavingsAccount getSavingsAccount() {
        return savingsAccount;
    }

    public void setSavingsAccount(SavingsAccount savingsAccount) {
        this.savingsAccount = savingsAccount;
    }

    public List<Appointment> getAppointmentList() {
        return appointmentList;
    }

    public void setAppointmentList(List<Appointment> appointmentList) {
        this.appointmentList = appointmentList;
    }

    public List<Recipient> getRecipientList() {
        return recipientList;
    }

    public void setRecipientList(List<Recipient> recipientList) {
        this.recipientList = recipientList;
    }



    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", primaryAccount=" + primaryAccount +
                ", savingsAccount=" + savingsAccount +
                ", appointmentList=" + appointmentList +
                ", recipientList=" + recipientList +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**UserDto.java**

```
package com.uwezotech.dto;

import com.uwezotech.validation.PasswordMatches;
import com.uwezotech.domain.Role;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.Set;


@PasswordMatches(message = "Password does not match")
public class UserDto {

    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Last name is required")
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Phone number is required")
    private String phone;
    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
    private String email;

    private boolean enabled;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Matching password is required")
    private String matchingPassword;

    public UserDto(Long id, @NotBlank(message = "First name is required") String firstName, @NotBlank(message = "Last name is required") String lastName, @NotBlank(message = "Phone number is required") String phone, @NotBlank(message = "Password is required") String username, @NotBlank(message = "Email is required") String email, boolean enabled, @NotBlank(message = "Password is required") String password, @NotBlank(message = "Matching password is required") String matchingPassword, Set<Role> roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.password = password;
        this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
    }

    public UserDto() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMatchingPassword() {
        return matchingPassword;
    }

    public void setMatchingPassword(String matchingPassword) {
        this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.uwezotech.service.userServiceImpl;

import com.uwezotech.dao.RoleDao;
import com.uwezotech.dao.UserDao;
import com.uwezotech.domain.User;
import com.uwezotech.service.AccountService;
import com.uwezotech.service.UserService;
import com.uwezotech.dto.UserDto;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;



@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl  implements UserService{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);
     @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
     @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;
     @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;




    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userDao.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public boolean checkUserExists(String username, String email) {
        if (checkUsernameExists(username) || checkEmailExists(username)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkUsernameExists(String username) {
        if (null != findByUsername(username)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    public boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
        if (null != findByEmail(email)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public void save(User user) {
        userDao.save(user);
    }

   public User createNewAccount(UserDto userDto){
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        user.setPhone(userDto.getPhone());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(roleDao.findByName("ROLE_USER")));
        user.setPrimaryAccount(accountService.createPrimaryAccount());
        user.setSavingsAccount(accountService.createSavingsAccount());
        return user;
    }


    public List<User> findUserList() {
        return userDao.findAll();
    }

    public void enableUser(String username) {

    }

    public void disableUser(String username) {

    }

}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.uwezotech.controllers;

import com.uwezotech.dao.RoleDao;
import com.uwezotech.domain.User;
import com.uwezotech.service.UserService;
import com.uwezotech.dto.UserDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class HomeController {   

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showRegister(ModelAndView modelAndView, UserDto userDto){
        modelAndView.addObject("userDto", userDto);
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        return modelAndView;

 }

 @PostMapping(value = "/submit-registration")
public ModelAndView saveUser(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute("userDto") @Valid final UserDto userDto, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors){
        User emailExists = userService.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        User userNameExists = userService.findByUsername(userDto.getUsername());
    System.out.println(emailExists);
    if(emailExists != null){
        modelAndView.setViewName("/register");
        bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "alreadyRegisteredEmail", "There is already a registered with email provided.");
    }
    if(userNameExists !=null){
        modelAndView.setViewName("/register");
        bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "alreadyRegisteredUsername", "There is already a user registered with username provided");
    }
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        modelAndView.setViewName("/register");
    }else{
        User user = userService.createNewAccount(userDto);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userService.save(user);
    }
    return modelAndView;

}

 }
```

Comment: No exceptions logged or errors returned to the browser?

Comment: yeah no exceptions or errors

Comment: Is the code, that's saving data even run?

Comment: @Andronicus Yes the code is running but there is not data showing in the database

Comment: I mean the single line, that does the saving. Also are there any logs?

Comment: You post almost all your code, but forget the most important one the `UserDao`. Dumping all your code isn't a very good way of asking a question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with that knowledge.